# android studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing an issue in `Android Studio` everything working fine before but after adding some `Jar` files for `Twitter` seems giving me this `Error`.

I have tried `Invalidate caches & Restart studio` so many times but it doesn't helped me. And also tried other solutions but none of them helped me.

**If i removed `twitter jar files` then project build successfully else it is showing same error again and again.**

**Error**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14.class
```

Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    // jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar')
}
```

I am stuck here any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Tried with `./gradlew clean` but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal execute in root project folder:

```
./gradlew clean
```

It helped me.

[More details](http://Error:Execution%20failed%20for%20task%20':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug')

Comment: I will try this afterwards and let you know if this work or not.